# How can I get Autohotkey to press a differnet button with a button input?

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

```
~LALT:: Send {DELETE DOWN}
~LALT UP:: Send {DELETE UP}
~NUMPAD0:: Send {DELETE DOWN}
~NUMPAD0 UP:: Send {DELETE UP}
```

There is my current code.  I want to make it so that when I'm holding down either Left Alt or Numpad 0, it will ALSO push down the Delete key.  My problem is that I cannot compile it, and I have very little knowledge to why it won't compile.

The reason I am doing this is because I have two separate hot keys for Push-to-talk voice program and I want FRAPS to record when I'm pushing either of them.

I get this error when I compile )= https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuSot.png

Comment: Your code compiles fine. And it works like you mentioned.

Comment: I suggest that you use AHK_L with SciTE4AutoHotkey. In SciTE4AutoHotkey  you can load your code and select tools-Compile. When you install I suggest you install the 32 bit version, this way it works on both 32/64 bit systems. Once you compile it to 64 bit, it will no longer work on 32 bit systems.

Comment: Everytime I hit compile in there I get this error: http://i.imgur.com/dBI5lSk.png

Comment: You are trying to compile AutoHotkey code with AutoIt's compiler. AutoHotkey and AutoIt are not the same. Rename you file to *.ahk and follow Robert Ilbrink's instructions to compile it.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Thanks.  I thought that AutoHotKey got a name change, so I wasn't aware.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it to use Windows' `win` keys with Display Fusion.

Even though I might set the hotkey the way I want it in Display Fusion, Windows won't let me override it - but AutoHotkey will!  So I set the hotkeys in Display Fusion to something I won't ever use or possibly remember, then I set the hotkeys I want in AutoHotkey , and use AutoHotkey to send the hotkeys I don't need to remember...  (clear as mud?)

```
;key commands to align to Display Fusion
#down::send, !#{down}
#up::send, !#{up}
#right::send, !#{right}
#left::send, !#{left}

#+down::send,+^#{down}
#+up::send,+^#{up}
#+right::send,+^#{right}
#+left::send,+^#{left}
```

(I know krazyito65 already has an answer, but in order to mark this question solved, someone needs to "answer" it).